# "Error 800A0005 - Invalid procedure call or argument" when writing to file

Tags: vbscript

```
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\output.txt", True)

Dim temp, key
temp = "mon pass"
key  = "qswx"
temp = Encrypt(temp,key)

Function encrypt(Str, key)
    ...
    ...
  Next
  encrypt = Newstr
End Function

objFile.WriteLine temp 'Error 800A0005 - Invalid procedure call or argument
```

The above code gives the following error in the last line:

> erreur 800a0005 argument ou appel de procedure incorrect
>   Microsoft VBScript error '800a0005'
>   Invalid Procedure call or argument

When I use

```
WScript.Echo temp
```

it works perfectly.

Comment: What line of code creates the error?

Comment: objFile.WriteLine temp

Comment: what to do to  save the result

Answer (score 1):

I've had this before when there are unicode charaters but I didn't create a unicode file.  Try

```
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\output.txt", True, True)
```

which uses the optional Unicode bool to support more char types. (ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createtextfile-method)